# PHP - Perform parsing rules on nested array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, transformation

So I have a nested array, that mimics a table layout (columns and rows):

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "row": "My name is Trevor\n"
        },
        {
            "row": "Can you see me?\n"
        },
        {
            "row": "\f"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "row": Hey there! Some other text.\n"
        },
        {
            "row": "What is up?\n"
        },
        {
            "row": "\f"
        }
    ],
    "3": [
        {
            "row": "Some text on the third column. First row."
        },
        {
            "row": "\f"
        }
    ]
}
```

So "1", "2", "3" are the columns and then under each column, there can be any number of rows.

Now I am trying to do, so my users can perform various parsing rules on either:

1. All columns and all rows.
2. Specific columns and all rows.

Whenever a column / row has been parsed, it should be returned to the "original array".

For this, I have created a class that will apply the different parsing rules I have in specified. Getting the parsing rule works fine. I am currently stuck in the actual text transformation/parsing aspect.

Consider I have a parsing rule called "regexTextReplace", that looks like this:

```
class regexTextReplace
{
    private $pattern;
    private $replacement;

    public function __construct(array $arguments)
    {
        $this->pattern = $arguments['pattern'];
        $this->replacement = $arguments['replacement'];
    }

    public function apply(array $table, $column = false): array
    {
        $table = $column ? $table[$column] : $table;

        return array_map('self::regex_replace', $table);
    }

    public function regex_replace(array $table)
    {
        return preg_replace($this->pattern, $this->replacement, $table);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
$options = [
    'pattern' => '/Trevor/i',
    'replacement' => 'Oliver',
];
$engine = new regexTextReplace($options);
$columns = $engine->apply($document->content, 1); //"1" is the specific column.
```

`$columns` returns:

```
[
  {
    "row": "My name is Oliver\n"
  },
  {
    "row": "Can you see my?\n"
  },
  {
    "row": "\f"
  }
]
```

***Two problems here:***

1. It successfully apply the parsing rule (Trever is replaced with Oliver). But it only returns the first column, but I want the entire original array to be transformed.
2. If I remove the `1` from the `apply()` method, I get below error:

```
Array to string conversion
```

on below line:

```
return preg_replace($this->pattern, $this->replacement, $table);
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction, so I can perform my parsing rule on any column or on all columns, and return the transformed data back to my original array?

Comment: As this looks pretty complicated: have you tried applying TDD to this? Like starting to write a test for the most simplest case, and then go forward with the next case that is a bit more difficult? This will help you to keep this class maintainable

Comment: See your conditions here: `$table = $column ? $table[$column] : $table;` table will come as array when the `column` argument is false value hence why it complains about `Array to string conversion`.

I would rather make the value of `table` consistent, that is, an array then simply loop through every time `apply()` receives a call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rewrite the `apply` function to loop over the entire table, processing each column if the `column` argument is not set, or if it matches the current table column:

```
public function apply(array $table, $column = false): array
{
    $out = array();
    foreach ($table as $col => $rows) {
        if ($column === false || $col == $column) {
            $out[$col] = array_map('self::regex_replace', $rows);
        }
        else {
            $out[$col] = $rows;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/P7NCu)

Comment: How would I specifiy if a specific column or all columns should be parsed? `$engine->apply($document->content);` will parse all columns. But say I only want the rule to be applied on the first column: `$engine->apply($document->content, 1);`

Comment: @oliverbj that's exactly right. If you look at my demo you'll see that I've modified your data slightly (adding `'Trevor'` to a row on column 2) so you can see that the single column version works as well as the whole table version.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was looking at your code before your edited. It works like a charm.

Comment: @oliverbj yeah, sorry about that. I didn't think through the change to `$column` properly and then realised later I had stuffed it up.

Comment: No worries. I just really appreciate all the help SO is providing :) Thanks to everyone for taking the time to answer my question - I've been stuck at this for 2 days now!

Comment: sorry just an extra question. Would you mind helping me extending it, so the 2nd parameter in the `apply` can take an array of columns? So I could say: `['1', '2']` and it will apply the rules to column 1 and 2, but not 3.

Comment: if it will always be an array, just replace `$col == $column` with `in_array($col, $column)`

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite your `apply` method to this:

```
public function apply(array $table, $columns = false): array
{
    $columns = $columns === false ? array_keys($table) : (array)$columns;

    return array_map(function ($column) use ($table, $columns) {
      return in_array($column, $columns) ? array_map('self::regex_replace', $table[$column]) : $table[$column];
    }, array_keys($table));
}
```

You can pass either a single column, or an array of columns, or nothing (`false`) to specify the columns you want adjusted.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/Kn4FY**

Comment: But OPs whole problem is that he wants to return the *entire* array even if he only processes one column...

Comment: @Nick I just realized that, haha. I'll edit my answer (though yours looks totally fine).

Comment: @oliverbj Edited my post to take into account Nick's remark.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop it and do the regex on all subarrays:

```
$content = json_decode($json, true);

$options = [
    'pattern' => '/Trevor/i',
    'replacement' => 'Oliver',
];
$engine = new regexTextReplace($options);
foreach($content as $key => $v){
    $columns[$key] = $engine->apply($content, $key);
}
var_dump($columns);
```

Working demo:
https://3v4l.org/Pk2rC

The benefit of looping in the "PHP" side instead of in the class is that you can still apply the regex to only one or two of the subarrays.
If you loop in the class then you need to pass more arguments to restrict the looping or do some type of array slicing.

Comment: That loop probably belongs in the class' `apply` function

Comment: Thanks Andreas!
This loop will look in all columns by default if I am not mistaken, correct? Since the `$key` is the 2nd parameter of the `apply()` function. If I added a `column => all` to my `$options` array, would I be able to pass that in instead? Since I want users to either parse all columns or only specific columns.

Comment: @Nick if I was to place this directly in the `apply()` method, how would I then call the actual `apply()` method inside the foreach?

Comment: It can be used either in the class or in the "PHP" code. Not sure about the variable names though. Your question doesn't indicate them.

Comment: @oliverbj you wouldn't need a foreach if you put the loop inside the `apply` function

Comment: @Andreas, in my original code I have this: `$columns = $engine->apply($document->content, 1); //"1" is the specific column.` Where the "1" is the column I want to apply the parsing rule to.

Comment: @Nick would you mind showing a quick example of that? Can't really wrap my head around that?

Comment: @oliverbj I know. And if you loop the json object in your first code block and use the key in that statement where you have "1" then it should work